# cannot use [AllowNull] in ValueTuple

Tags: c#, c#-8.0

I had code like this:

```
    public void F(int i, (int k,  object v) tuple) { ... }
```

I try to make this code to compile without errors or warnings in both C# 8.0 with `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` and C# 7.3

as v *can* be null I tried:

```
    public void F(int i, (int k,  [AllowNull] object v) tuple) { ... }
```

However I get:

> Error CS0270  Array size cannot be specified in a variable declaration (try initializing with a 'new' expression)

Which doesn't make sense to me ..

(note that if I remove the value tuple `public void F(int i, int k,  [AllowNull] object v tuple) { ... }` everything is fine)

Is there a particular issue with value tuple parameters and [AllowNull] ? any way to solve this ?

Comment: How about `(int k, object? v)`?

Comment: You can't put attributes on the members of a value tuple. The `?` syntax invokes different parts of the compiler that handles this in a different way, lifting it out to an attribute on the parameter (in this case), and the compiler will carry the knowledge of the nullability along with it, but the type, the ValueTuple type used, has no notion of these attributes. So basically, the `?` gets special treatment, the attributes does not.

Comment: Before you enable nullable reference types, variables are considered nullable oblivious. Once you enable nullable reference types, all those variables are non-nullable. The compiler will issue warnings if those variables aren't initialized to non-null values.

Another likely source of warnings is return values when the value hasn't been initialized.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen thanks!  but if I use ? it will give a warning when nullable is disabled (
Warning CS8632 The annotation for nullable reference types should only be used in code within a '#nullable' annotations context.)

Comment: does that mean this code cannot be compiled to give no warnings in both cases ?

Comment: I believe you're right, you can't do it, not with out #if directives.